# Get generated spool file Swiftmailer/Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, mailer, spool

I am moving from instant sending to spooling messages using Swiftmailer/Symfony2. I have everything working but I can't seem to get the path to the generated file after I do $mailer->send(). SF2 or Swiftmailer creates the file in my spool directory, but through the Swiftmailer instance is there a way that I can get that generated filename?

In case someone is wondering, I would like to get that file to keep a record of emails sent.. and I would like to include the serialization of that file...

Note: looping through the directory and getting the files is not an option as multiple files can be created relatively at the same time...

**Update #1**

Here is my dirty way around this..

1. Create a new spool and set a temporary path with a hash..something like `$newSpool = new \Swift_FileSpool($this->container->getParameter('swiftmailer.spool.default.file.path')."/".$hash/`
2. After the `$mailer->send()` the file will be inside the hash folder
3. Read that folder and in theory it should only contain 1 file
4. Log any desire information and the file content and name
5. Move the file out of the hash folder to the actual spool directory to continue the process normally.

Again, this is my dirty way of getting a hold of this file name... sadly I don't see any other way around at this moment and the documentation is not helping as I can't find how to use Swift Events in 2.8+

I will leave this question opened until a  better answer comes up.

Comment: If you want to keep copies, why wouldn't you send them to an BCC email address of yours, that just holds those mails?

Comment: @KhorneHoly I would like to have something more flexible for users... like the ability to re-send the email..and also see the emails that are pending/sent/failed in a list

Comment: Why don't you store the final rendered version in a database with all required metadata. Would make your live easier or store it to another location

Comment: @ChrisWest I've thought of storing a serialized version of the Swift_Message instance but I would also like to keep track of the spooling.. like if it's spooled,pending,failure or simply sent if not in the folder..